# Gtkmm 'no matching function for call' errors

Tags: c++, function, callback, gtkmm, signal-handling

I am a beginner and learning Gtkmm by following their official documentation.

But this example:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-menus-examples.html.en#menu-example-main

is not working and I am getting these kind of errors:

```
examplewindow.cc: In constructor ‘ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()’:
examplewindow.cc:18:67: error: no matching function for call to 
‘Gio::SimpleActionGroup::add_action(const char [12], 
sigc::bound_mem_functor0<void, ExampleWindow>)’
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_new_generic));
                                                               ^
```

The above error is pointed for this bit of code:

```
refActionGroup->add_action("newstandard",
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_new_generic));
```

But "on_menu_file_new_generic" function does exist. So if the callback function does exist, then how come it says 'no matching function'?

Any help?

Comment: Compiles fine here. Are you sure you are using 3.0 and not 2.0 version of gtkmm? (the error complains about `add_action`, not about `on_menu_file_new_generic`).

Comment: @n.m. Yes I am compiling using 3.0

`g++ main.cc examplewindow.cc -o run `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`

Comment: Also please show the entire error message set, not just the first few lines.

Comment: gcc version 4.8.1

Here is the full error message: [http://pastebin.com/TZEDbhDr ]

Comment: Can you try to compile this simple file: http://pastebin.com/6KgftTHF ? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @n.m. No errors with `g++ a.cpp -c pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the exact code shown on that page? Can you preprocess your example with `gcc -E` and upload it somewhere?

Comment: @n.m. Yes the same exact code. Is this is what you are asking?
 [ http://202.164.53.122/~gurjot/log ]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jKCzJTo.png

Comment: I was trying another way to do that, and even if the code should be as it is, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because of older version of glibmm library. My current version of glibmm is 2.37.4 that does not support this method.

This overloaded add_action() method first appeared in glibmm 2.37.6, so in order to get past this error I need to install newer version of glibmm.

Hope others will be able to resolve their errors as well.

Comment: And if you want to stick with your current version of glibmm, then I suggest you follow this example https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm-documentation/tree/examples/book/menus/main_menu?h=gtkmm-3-2